# How to change columns and rows in my csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a csv file with this kind of data:

[image]

But I would like to have the columns Americas, Asia, Europe, Africa etc. with all the corresponding "vdem_corr" values under it.
How can I change this in python?

Comment: Please put your CSV content as **text**. We have no time to rewrite the content from your picture. And what about multiple occurrences of some regions?
How do you want these numbers to be presented in the result?

Comment: Use: `print(df.set_index('region').T)`

Comment: The table consists of more than 100 rows, I want a command to do it automatically. I want 5 continents as different columns and under it every number that belongs to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is:

```
result = df.groupby('region').apply(lambda grp: pd.Series(
    grp.vdem_corr.values)).unstack(level=1).T
```

The advantage over the answer by *Prahken* is that my result has
much less *NaN* values.

Try on your own and compare.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.read_csv(...) 
df.pivot(columns='region', values='vdem_corr')
```